# inner join and how to avoid double step

Tags: sql, sql-server

To get the info I am looking for I always have to perform double steps. I am pretty sure it is possible to avoid it. That's how I get the info I need at the moment:

```
SELECT        AppUser.*
FROM          AppUser WHERE Email='xxx@xxx.com'
```

This would give me the the users Id, which is in this example 38.

After that I make a second query:

```
SELECT        Follower.*, AppUser.*
FROM          Follower INNER JOIN
              AppUser ON Follower.ToUserId = AppUser.Id

WHERE FromUserId=38
```

And that's the result I like to have.

Here the question: How can I get the infos I need directly = not getting first the Id? I don't need the Id for my reply.

What I would like is to have a query answer searching with the Email directly.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and explain what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: In the follower table we manage friends relations: here in this example the FromUserId 38 follows many users Ids in the table ToUserId. So the idea is to get a friends list of user 38 and have then the ToUserId Email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only columns of Follower tables then you can use sub query also.

```
SELECT *
FROM  Follower 
WHERE Follower.ToUserId  
IN (SELECT Id FROM AppUser WHERE Email='xxx@xxx.com' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your second query's WHERE to:

```
WHERE AppUser.Email='xxx@xxx.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you put the where statement to main query?

```
SELECT        Follower.*, AppUser.*
FROM          Follower INNER JOIN
              AppUser ON Follower.ToUserId = AppUser.Id
WHERE AppUser.Email='xxx@xxx.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference `AppUsers` in the `WHERE` clause.  You don't need two queries:

```
SELECT f.*, au.*
FROM Follower f INNER JOIN
     AppUser au
     ON f.ToUserId = au.Id
WHERE au.Email = 'xxx@xxx.com';
```

Note that I introduced table aliases as abbreviations for the table names.  This makes the query easier to write and to read.

In addition, I would advise you to list the columns you want in the `SELECT`.  You might have issues if columns have the same name in both tables.